# $_REQUEST doesn't work

Tags: php, request

I have code

```
<form action="insert1.php" form method="POST">

<input type="text" name="product" /></p>

<input type="submit" value="Add">
```

And

```
$mysqli = configuration();

$product = $_REQUEST['$product'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Odiet (product) VALUES ('$product')";

if($mysqli ->query($sql)===TRUE){echo "ok";}
else{echo "not ok";}
$mysqli ->close();
```

It adds empty string without text.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use request, you should know which one to use. Also learn about security and use prepared statements.

Comment: would you please tell me why don't use $_REQUEST

Comment: @layvin may i know if the $product to product was the problem then how `It was adding empty string without text. without sending an error`  ?

Comment: I don't know, It gave answer 'ok' and added empty string. Now, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this string:

```
$product = $_REQUEST['$product'];
```

With this

```
$product = $_REQUEST['product'];
```

Answer (score -1):

I just fix one error in you code and you need to put it like this:

```
$mysqli = configuration();

$product = $_REQUEST['product'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Odiet (product) VALUES ('$product')";

if($mysqli ->query($sql)===TRUE){echo "ok";}
else{echo "not ok";}

$mysqli ->close();
```

You get values from html form by field name, but without dolar sign before.

And be aware that your code is not safe. Don't put raw user data in your sql statement, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understood that problem was with dolar sign.

Comment: This is not safe! Don't use queries directly. You should bind parameters/values instead. If you use variables inside a SQL query directly, someone can inject queries in that variable.

Comment: @MAChitgarha Yeah, I just copied authors code and change wrong name of field and i write note that his code is not safe and he should use prepared statement.

Answer (score -1):

You should know which one to use, `$_REQUEST` opens up a huge security risk to your database. Also use preprared statements.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Odiet (product) VALUES (?)";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['product']);

  if($stmt->execute()){
    echo "ok";
  } else {
    echo "not ok";
  }
}
```

There is also little use in closing the db connection as this is automatically done after script execution.

Comment: Thank you, I will use preprared statements